# Bootstrap navbarDropdown doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got problem with navbar dropdown. It show up properly but when I try to expand category doesn't happen anything. Also copied templary straight from Bootstrap's documentation. Doesn't seem like I can figure it out what is wrong by myself.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap beginning</title>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/styles.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown link
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my directory: [Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrbim.png)

Comment: Did you check if there are any errors in your console?

Comment: Oh yes, I do. Forgot to post logs here. That's how it goes: https://imgur.com/a/lhZup

Comment: Well dude, it's not finding your files.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your console, the requiered js could not be loaded.
So check your paths for the files that you can see in the console with an error of 404. Your .css files are getting loaded from /src/css/ but your js files from /js/ it should be src/js. You may want to check that... . I´m affraid no one can help you find your files on your webserver!